# pointers as generics c#

Tags: c#, .net, templates, generics, pointers

Does anyone have an idea if it is possible to have primitive types as generic argument.

Notice, before you start talking about how I should not use pointers.

The images are raw data arrays allocated using [IPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Performance_Primitives), for most part I will use IPP, this part is the conversion from unmanaged to managed data in a prefered format when individual processing of the data in a non IPP supported way is required or prefered.

I need the following functions in byte,float,short combinations, and instead of writing all combinations explicit, i would prefer some generic/template stuff in the style of

```
private static unsafe List<PixelF> GetPixels<Timg,Tmask>(
  VMImage img, 
  int band, 
  VMImage imgMask, 
  int bandMask)
```

where Timg and TMask can be one (byte,short or float)

right now, one function looks like this.

```
private static unsafe List<PixelF> GetPixels_FloatImg_ByteMask(
  VMImage img, 
  int band, 
  VMImage imgMask, 
  int bandMask)
{
  List<PixelF> pixValues = new List<PixelF>();
  int r, c;
  int imgSrcOffset = img.LineLength - img.Width;
  int imgMaskOffset = imgMask.LineLength - imgMask.Width;
  float* pf_imgSrc = (float*)img.GetRoiPointer(band);
  byte* pb_imgMask = (byte*)imgMask.GetRoiPointer(bandMask);
  for (r = 0; r < img.Height; r++) // Loop over rows
  {
    for (c = 0; c < img.Width; c++) // Loop over columns
    {
      if (*pb_imgMask > 0)
      {
        pixValues.Add(new PixelF(c, r, (float)*pf_imgSrc));
      }
      ++pf_imgSrc;
      ++pb_imgMask;
    }
    pf_imgSrc += imgSrcOffset;
    pb_imgMask += imgMaskOffset;
  }
  return pixValues;
}
```

EDIT**
The following is how I would like to do:

```
private static unsafe List<PixelF> GetPixels<Timg, Tmask>(
  VMImage img, 
  int band, 
  VMImage imgMask, 
  int bandMask)
{
  List<PixelF> pixValues = new List<PixelF>();
  int r, c;
  int imgSrcOffset = img.LineLength - img.Width;
  int imgMaskOffset = imgMask.LineLength - imgMask.Width;
  Timg* pf_imgSrc = (Timg*)img.GetRoiPointer(band);
  Tmask* pb_imgMask = (Tmask*)imgMask.GetRoiPointer(bandMask);
  for (r = 0; r < img.Height; r++) // Loop over rows
  {
    for (c = 0; c < img.Width; c++) // Loop over columns
    {
      if (*pb_imgMask > 0)
      {
        pixValues.Add(new PixelF(c, r, (float)*pf_imgSrc));
      }
      ++pf_imgSrc;
      ++pb_imgMask;
    }
    pf_imgSrc += imgSrcOffset; 
    pb_imgMask += imgMaskOffset;
  }
  return pixValues;
}
```

I Expect I could do that in c++ as template, but is it possible in c#

Edit***

As shambulator pointed out, simply trying to do

```
private static unsafe GetPixels_ByteImg_FloatMask<TImg, TMask>(
  VMImage img, 
  int band, 
  VMImage imgMask, 
  int bandMask) 
    where TImg : struct where TMask : struct
    {
      TImg* pb_imgSrc = (TImg*)img.GetRoiPointer(band);
    }
```

gives the error 
(Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type.)

Edit****
Basicaly, what I need to know is the size of the pointer (byte,short,float) and ofcourse, it must be cast correctly to a float later on,

Comment: Yes, primitive types can be used as generic type arguments. List<int> for example is common.

Comment: It sounds like when you say "primitive types" you mean value types. If so, then what issue are you running into? Generics work for both value and reference types (and you can even constrain a generic to where it can only be one or the other).

Comment: but, what you want to do is not generic. Generic types can be primitive value types of course, they can be any other type too, unless you apply a constraint.

Comment: Ok, I need to clarify a bit, this line  float* pf_imgSrc = (float*)img.GetRoiPointer(band); should become something like TImg* pf_imgSrc = (Timg*)img.GetRoiPointer(band);

Comment: You need to clarify a bit more. It took some playing with code to discover that, if you add a generic type parameter `T`, the root of the problem seems to be that you can't declare `T* pf_imgSrc` (*Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type.*) Not even with a `struct` generic constraint.

Comment: @shambulator yes, I noticed that, I will do.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to do this in a separate Managed C++ assembly, aka C++/CLI, where the public .NET API exposes your generically typed interface and the "unsafe" pointer-related stuff happens in native code.

Comment: its a good idea, Im afraid that i can't sell it in my company, since we are quite relegius about converting everything to c# instead of c++.
  
would it be possible to have this managed c++ wrapper in anyCPU? that would be a good selling point if possible.

Comment: No, but you can follow the procedure outlined here http://scottbilas.com/blog/automatically-choose-32-or-64-bit-mixed-mode-dlls/ to automatically load the correct native library. I guess you can't have it both ways: unsafe pointer use and only c#...